# natbib using et al with econometrica style

Tags: natbib

Hi I'm using `natbib` with econometrica.  For many of my citations the author lists are
very long, and I'd like them to show in the text as first
author + "et al.".  How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please indicate the threshold above which the truncation (to firstauthor et al) in citations should take place: Do you want to truncate if there are more than 2, 3, 4, etc. authors?

Comment: Incidentally, do you use the old style file `econometrica.bst` (which dates back to ca. 1994) or the newer (ca. 2000) style file `ecta.bst`? The reason I ask is that the newer file seems to be set up to truncate lists of authors longer than two (i.e., three or more authors) automatically to "FirstAuthor et al".